# How do you enable Hotspot Wifi Sharing on Nexus 5 Android M version on Sprint, Tmobile, and AT&T?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, 6.0-marshmallow, developer-preview

I just loaded the Android M preview version as of July 2015. I'm also on the Sprint network and my phone is rooted. How can I enable wifi hotspot ability on Android M?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried it, and this worked for me:

(Nexus 6, Android M Preview 3, Sprint)

1. With root browser go to `/system/` and open `build.prop` in a text editor.
2. Add `net.tethering.noprovisioning=true` to the bottom.
3. Save and reboot.

In Android L, I also had to do the `tether_dun_required` thing, but now that database just doesn't show up for me in Android M.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by connecting your rooted Nexus 5 phone to a computer and run the command in the command prompt or terminal: `adb shell`

After it connects to your phone run the command:

`settings put global tether_dun_required 0`

Then reboot and it should work!

Comment: does not work on android m preview 3 -- i get this error: Tethering or Hotspot Error -- Unable to connect to data network; You may not be subscribed to Tethering or Hotspot service; please contact your phone company.

Answer (score 1):

After Android M (Mashmallow) Preview 3 -- You need to do the following to get tether / wifi hotspot to work:

1. On your Windows computer open up a terminal and type: `adb shell`
2. In the terminal window, type: " `su -` " (check your phone to approve)
3. `echo "net.tethering.noprovisioning=true" >> /system/build.prop`
4. Run this command: `content insert --uri content://settings/global --bind name:s:tether_dun_required --bind value:i:0`
5. Reboot

Verified; working on Android M preview 3 as of 9-21-2015.

Comment: cant get it working on nexus 6 with android M stock rom. the *content* command fails when trying to do an insert. this is for sprint too.