# What does tether_dun_required do?

Tags: system

I see lots of mentions of this option on Android sites, [including Android.StackExchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116508/how-do-you-enable-hotspot-wifi-sharing-on-nexus-5-android-m-version-on-sprint-t), but I don't see any technical exploitation for what it does. What does this option actually do?

Answer (score 1):

Tells telephony manager dial up networking emulation not required, not sure if thats actually required if you use net.tethering.noprovisioning=true in build.prop you can see the telephony and tethering code in the links below

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/355dbae680994002c48d7a66cb276a65393ecbbb/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/Tethering.java

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what it does, but a lot of people seem tho think this in `adb shell` gets them free tethering.

```
su
settings put global tether_dun_required 0
exit
```

Comment: For my phone it isn't free tethering, it's tethering at all. Or maybe it's due to chaning SIM cards?