# How to enable WiFi sharing in Android 8.1 in LG Nexus 5x

Tags: wifi-hotspot, 8.1-oreo, nexus-5x

Currently, when we try to turn on Hotspot in Nexus 5x, then WiFi just gets disabled and only mobile data is shared over WiFi instead of already connected WiFi (broadband). Using Netshare WiFi sharing on LG Nexus 5x isn't working all that great for WiFi sharing with Mac.

When Samsung Galaxy S7 and above can achieve this feat, then I guess that there should be a way to achieve the same for stock Android in Nexus 5x.

Is there a way to enable wifi sharing in Android 8.1 in LG Nexus 5x when we turn on the default hotspot on? Is there a way to share WiFi in Nexus 5x on Android 8.1 using methods such as the one mentioned at [How do you enable Hotspot Wifi Sharing on Nexus 5 Android M version on Sprint, Tmobile, and AT&T?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116508/how-do-you-enable-hotspot-wifi-sharing-on-nexus-5-android-m-version-on-sprint-t)?

Comment: Regarding the question you linked, it might be you misunderstood the situation. It was to enable the mobile hotspot in the first place since some mobile operators disable it.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to use Wi-Fi and hotspot at the same time on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/201024/44325). Some manufacturers and modern devices have this feature inbuilt, but others need some hacks to use this.